# Функция для переработки массива

Tags: mysql, php, sql

$people = многомерный, ассоциативный массив, который принял значения с запроса к БД

В общем, в файле есть проход и достаются всякие имена, фамилии с БД и т.п.
Но мне также надо, внутри цикла

```
      <?foreach ($people as $scholar):?>
```

Создать еще один массив многомерный, пытаюсь это сделать через функцию selectChild.
Проблема в том, что в массиве потом лежат ресурсы

```
       <?foreach ($people as $scholar):?>
     <?$child = selectChild($people);?>

        //Тут всякие вставки ...

        <?endforeach?>
_______________________________________

      ///Вот сама функция

     function selectChild($people){

     $mass = array();
     $children = array();
     $children1 = array();
     $children2 = array();

       foreach ($people as $delete){

       $id = $delete['children'];
        $id1 = $delete['children1'];
        $id2 = $delete['children2'];

        $delete['children'] != 0 ? $children = mysql_query("SELECT name, surname FROM datacenter WHERE id = '$id'") : $children = 0;
        $delete['children1'] != 0 ? $children1 = mysql_query("SELECT name, surname FROM datacenter WHERE id = '$id'") : $children = 0;
         $delete['children2'] != 0 ? $children2 = mysql_query("SELECT name, surname FROM datacenter WHERE id = '$id'") : $children = 0;

       $mass[] = array($children1, $children2);
       }
      return $mass;
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

Ыыы, прикольно:

```
$delete['children'] != 0 ? $children = mysql_query("SELECT name, surname FROM datacenter WHERE id = '$id'") : $children = 0;
```

Лучше:

```
$children = $delete['children'] != 0 ? mysql_query("SELECT name, surname FROM datacenter WHERE id = '$id'") : 0;
```

А по поводу вопроса: а где он?

Answer (score 0):

mysql_query возвращает ресурс. нужен массив - обработай результат запроса. А вообще так писать это караул какой то. Насколько может быть ясно, тебе нужно юзеров вытянуть из базы. Неужели нельзя просто всех вытащить? Если даже нет, то зачем отправлять 3 запроса в каждой итерации цикла, если можно отправить 1? Или если уж и правда все записи не нужны, то наверное лучше воспользоваться оператором IN () и вытянуть всё что нужно одним запросом, а не городить такие огороды.